# Getting error "Unable to resolve module xmlhttprequest" while using react-native and cljs-ajax

Tags: react-native, clojurescript, re-natal, cljs-ajax

I am using re-natal along with cljs-ajax, according to https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax/blob/master/docs/faq.md#react-native-why-does-bundling-fail-on-my-compiled-project

```
"react-native": {
   "xmlhttprequest": false
}
```

By adding these lines on package.json fixes this problem, i have added those lines in my package.json but still getting the same error.

Also added those line .re-natal but same result.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also see this issue: https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax/issues/188. They mention the package.json fix stopped working.